# ElasticSearch matching paths

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I have an index with various types where user may have different access permissions for each type. All records have `path` field that is used to determine what user can and can't see. Here's an example of records:

```
id: 12   type: Project  path: projects/12                   content: …
id: 874  type: Task     path: projects/12/public/tasks/874  content: …
id: 3    type: User     path: users/4                       content: …
```

If I know that user can see `users/12`, `users/14`, `users/18`, and `projects/*/public/*`, how would you structure a query that filters only matching records and searches inside `content` field? This is easy with SQL (and modeled around FULLTEXT index of a database), but I need to make it work with ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a simple bool query. For the particular instance you mentioned, try the query below (replace `<index>` with the actual index name). This will perform a search across all types. Of course your code needs to be general enough to generate the appropriate `should` clauses (term or wildcard etc).

```
POST <index>/_search
{
    "fields": [
       "content"
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "term": {
                      "path": "users/12"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "term": {
                      "path": "users/14"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "wildcard": {
                      "path": "projects/*/public/*"
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```